# Best way to create a dynamic Select (Dropdown) list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, drop-down-menu, selectlist

I'm using jQuery and jqGrid.

I'm trying to populate a select list dynamically, one for each row and I need to add a click event to it.  When the select list is being populated I grab the index of the item I want selected, and then after all items are add I'm trying to set the selected item.

I've tried

```
$("#taskList")[0].selectedIndex = taskIndex;
$("#taskList").selectOptions(taskIndex, true);
$("#taskList").val(1); //Tried to see if I could select any index and no luck.
$("#taskList option[value=" + taskIndex + "]").attr("selected", true);
```

So this means I'm probably populating the list incorrectly...

```
var taskList = document.createElement("select");
var taskIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < result.TaskTypes.length; i++) {
   $(taskList).addOption(result.TaskTypes[i].TaskId, result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName);
   if (result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName == rowData.TaskType)
    taskIndex = i;
}
```

Is there a better way?

I tried this but I couldn't add the click event to it.  The proper item was selected though.

```
var taskList = "<select name='taskList' Enabled='true'>";
for (var i = 0; i < result.TaskTypes.length; i++) {
    if (result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName == rowData.TaskType)
        taskList += "<option selected> " + result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName + "</option>";
    else
    taskList += "<option>" + result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName + "</option>";
}
taskList += "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it-  a good solid 8 hours later.

```
var taskList = "<select name='taskList' Enabled='true' onClick='$(\"#hoursBx\").valid()' >";
for (var i = 0; i < result.TaskTypes.length; i++) {
    if (result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName == rowData.TaskType)
        taskList += "<option selected> " + result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName + "</option>";
    else
        taskList += "<option>" + result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName + "</option>";
}
taskList += "</select>";
```

I'm using [jQuery's Validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to verify the value in the $("#hoursBx") (a text box in the current row).

Adding the onClick works.

Comment: String concatenation can be slow in a 'for' loop instead append to an array and join at the end `var htmlArray = []; htmlArray.push("<option selected>",text,"</option>"); var html = htmlArray.join("");`

Answer (score 4):

The way I would have done it, is in your first example - instead of using the jQuery API for addOption, use the DOM API, like this:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = result.TaskTypes[i].TaskName;
option.value = result.TaskTypes[i].TaskId;
option.onclick = myClickHandler;
taskList.add(option, null);
```

Then after the loop you can just use:

```
taskList.selectedIndex = taskIndex;
```

to have the select list positioned to your required default selection.

I haven't used jQuery extensively, but I think its a good idea not to neglect the DOM API - its often not as convenient as the shortcuts that jQuery and other libraries offer, but these extend DOM capabilities and should not come instead of the DOM.

Comment: Not working...

taskList.add(option);  threw an exception. "htmlfile: Invalid argument."

Changed to $(taskList).add(option);
Its not adding items to taskList after I changed it.

Checked and innerHTML and Value are being set. 

Ideas??

Comment: I get a failure with add() as well, not sure why - its a documented API. Anyway, the DOM method appendChild() works great for me.

Comment: eh. You probably want to use taskList.add(option,null) to add an option to the bottom of the list. Calling it with a single parameter doesn't work indeed (I was under the assumption that the last parameter is optional and defaults to null).

Comment: Good news bad news....
Good- appendChild() works.
Bad - Still can't set what item I want selected. --> awesome :(

Comment: I've just edited my answer, and I think you'll find all the details you need in there :-)

Comment: Tired 
taskList.add(option, null); and I still get the "htmlfile: Type mismatch." error

I tried 
$(taskList).add(option, null); and its not populating taskList.

Am I having an issue with 
var taskList = document.createElement("select");

Comment: Are you using IE? what error do you get with the createElement() call ?

Comment: IE6.
I get the error thrown in Studio.  (sorry its not thrown in IE) 
I might need to add 
$(taskList).attr({id:"taskList"});
??

I gotta restart my machine, be back in a few.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, can't help you there: IE6 is not my turf. I'm not trying to be an elitist or something, but I'm haven't supported it for a long time now. For example, my company does web widgets for tier 1 web sites, and we only support IE7 (and 8 when it will come out).

Answer (score 2):

Falling under the "better way" category, JQuery lets you use an [each loop](http://docs.jquery.com/Each) instead of creating the for loops manually.

```
jQuery.each(result.TaskTypes, function(i, val) {
      $("#" + i).append(document.createTextNode(" - " + val));
    });
```

Comment: Tried this too.  No luck.
Quick question about the  "$("#" + i)."
How does it know what element to append to. I would need to do something like this..
$("#taskList " + i) ???
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set the selected index like this:

```
$("#taskList").selectedIndex = taskIndex;
```

Comment: Ah, you don't have id="taskList" on your select - that's why it's not working

Comment: Indeed, this should probably solve the issue if you just add `id="taskList"` to the select element.

Comment: Tried 
var taskList = document.createElement("select");
$(taskList).attr({ id: "taskList" });

no luck

Comment: Put the id in your markup. If you must do it via JavaScript then you're looking for one of: $('<select id="taskList"/>') or, if you already have the element: taskList.attr('id', 'taskList'). Look up for the documentation for 'attr' if you're still confused (this is a good idea anyway, actually :)).

Comment: Ya, I generally try to do this.  Tried but having the ID defined didn't help.  I end up adding an OnClick in the markup.  Thanks though.